# Accessing parent scope from a child controller with ControllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

How can I achieve the following using Controller-As approach:

```
app.controller("parentCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.parentObj = {prop1: "not set", prop2: "something"};
   $scope.doSomething = function(){...}
})
.controller("childCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.parentObj.prop1 = "changed";
});

<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  {{prop1}}
  <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
    {{prop2}}
    <button ng-click="doSomething()">Do</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

***without making assumptions about how the parent controller is aliased in the view***, i.e. no `{{pc.prop2}}`.

In other words, I would like to benefit from scope inheritance while using Controller-As approach. The question is **How**?

```
app.controller("parentCtrl", function(){
   this.parentObj = {prop1: "not set", prop2: "something"};
   this.doSomething = function(){...}
})
.controller("childCtrl", function($scope){

   // $scope.parentObj is undefined!
});
```

Comment: It's not. I specifically asked "without making assumptions about how the parent controller is aliased". The answer you linked to doesn't provide this solution

Comment: $scope.$parent is not the alias of the parent for me

Comment: No, it's not - although that doesn't use the inherited scope (what if it's `$parent.$parent`?) But in any case, with Controller-As, one defines the ViewModel with `this.vmProperty`, rather than `$scope.vmProperty`. With this, `$scope.$parent.vmProperty` is undefined.

Comment: Well... you can't the whole idea of controller as is to be explicitly used on the view.
So you could use Controller As, you could use $parent and you could also use the dot notation like you did. I really can't see where you're trying to get in this question

Comment: Amended the question to clarify

Comment: @NewDev did you found the answer? I'm stuck with the same questions

Comment: @PedroJusto, I've [answered my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647460/accessing-inherited-scope-with-controller-as-approach) that is related to this one.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `as` syntax to define a controller then to access parent scope variable in **child controller** use following :

```
var userData = $scope.parentCtrl.user;
```

Where `parentCtrl` is name of parent controller using `as` syntax and user is a variable defined in same controller.

Comment: I specified in the question (in bolded text): "without making assumptions about how the parent controller is aliased in the view"